# Duplicate code in vue.js single file component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In one of my components some part of template is repeated twice.

Is it possible to do somthing like this?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if='value'>
        *** code here ***
        include 'path_to_file.vue.part'
        </div>
        <div v-else>
        ** another code here ***
        include 'path_to_file.vue.part'
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: You can create a vue component of it?

Comment: Yes, I can but it will be hard. I just want to paste some repeated code.

Comment: But creating a small component is the usual way to deal with this. What makes it especially hard?

Comment: @LinusBorg Nothing makes it harder, he is just lazy :D :D

Comment: Time to choose an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [(named) slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots):

```
<slot name="common"></slot>
```

Then in the template you're "importing":

```
<p slot="common">some</p>
```

Comment: Nope, this code is harder. It includes other components.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternate the second `v-if` like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if='value'>
        *** code here ***
        include 'path_to_file.vue.part'
        </div>
        <div v-if='!value'>
        ** another code here ***
        include 'path_to_file.vue.part'
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```